# Regex Crossword

Tags: regex

I'm doing a RegEx crossword online and came across this one:

http://regexcrossword.com/challenges/doublecross/puzzles/2

My answer :

`A A T 
 E A M`

was wrong according to the site and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top row left is (CAT|A-T)+ which means it has to either be "CAT" or "A-T" exactly, I believe.

The middle row bottom is [A\-T], so "-" can go in the top middle.

Comment: You're right. I was treating the '-' character like it was describing a range of characters.